# InsertWithChildrenAsync() and duplicate primary keys

Tags: c#, sqlite, database-design, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I get a list of objects from a webservice. The data should be stored in a SQLite database. Thereby I can store the first item in the database with `InsertWithChildrenAsync()`, on the second I get an exception and the app crashes.

Class definition:

```
public class Color
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Color))]
    public string FavoriteColorId { get; set; }
    [OneToOne(CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.All)]
    public Color FavoriteColor { get; set; }
}
```

Initialization:

```
var dbPath = DependencyService.Get<IStorageService>().GetFilePathForDB();
DependencyService.Get<IStorageService>().DeleteFile(dbPath);
var db = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
await db.CreateTableAsync<Color>();
await db.CreateTableAsync<Person>();
```

Code demonstrating the issue:

```
var pers1 = new Person()
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "John",
    FavoriteColor = new Color() { Code = "FF0000", Name = "Red" }
};

var pers2 = new Person()
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Doe",
    FavoriteColor = new Color() { Code = "FF0000", Name = "Red" }
};

await db.InsertWithChildrenAsync(pers1, true);
await db.InsertWithChildrenAsync(pers2, true);
```

Error message

> SQLite.SQLiteException: Constraint

This doesn't happen if I use

```
var pers2 = new Person()
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Doe",
    FavoriteColor = new Color() { Code = "00FF00", Name = "Green" }
};
```

The problem is that the same primary key is inserted twice. One solution would be to use auto increment, but then the same data is stored multiple times. How can I use the same data for different objects? The data from the webservice is parsed and later stored in the database. I don't hold the objects in memory all the time. Otherwise I could use something like

```
Color red = new Color { Code = "00FF00", Name = "Green" };
pers1.FavoriteColor = red;
pers2.FavoriteColor = red;
```

Do I need a many-to-many table? What about deletion? Currently, I'm planning to use `DeleteAsync()`, but the entry can't be deleted entirely, because another instance is using it. Does the method take this into account?

What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a complex data structure like me, you can do the following: Primary keys, which don't use the autoincrement flag `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]`, have to be dealed with seperately.

For insertions, don't use `CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeInsert`. Instead you have to insert them manually. E.g.

```
await StoreColorAsync(db, red);
await db.InsertWithChildrenAsync(pers1, false);

public async Task StoreColorAsync(SQLiteAsyncConnection db, Color color)
{
    if (color == null)
        return;

    var foundItem = await GetColorAsync(db, color.Code);
    if (foundItem != null)
    {
        await db.UpdateAsync(color);
    }
    else
    {
        await db.InsertAsync(color);
    }
}

public async Task<Color> GetColorAsync(SQLiteAsyncConnection db, string colorCode)
{
    var queryResult = await db.Table<Color>().Where(c => c.Code == colorCode).CountAsync();
    if (queryResult > 0)
    {
        return await db.GetAsync<Color>(colorCode);
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

For deletion, only use `CascadeOperations = CascadeOperation.CascadeDelete` for entries with the autoincrement flag. Here I leave the other entries in the database, which will be perhaps reused later. On some special events (e.g. logout) I clear all tables.

Comment: Instead of checking for existence in `GetColorAsync()` you could directly use `FindAsync()` - it returns `null` if not found. However, in `StoreColorAsync()` just checking for existence instead of getting the item would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting this object twice:

```
new Color() { Code = "00FF00", Name = "Green" }
```

Therefore you are obtaining a Primary Key constraint error. I'd recommend you to check for existence of that element before inserting it to database.

Comment: I get that, but I'm only inserting with `InsertWithChildrenAsync()`. If I follow your advice I'd have to check for each property of `Person` if the entry exists. And if yes, fetch that from the database, assign it to the person and then use `InsertWithChildrenAsync()` again? What about deletion? This makes it much more complex and would lead to storing the data manually. `InsertWithChildrenAsync()` seems not to be suitable for any complex data. So there is no easier way?

Comment: Well, yes. If you try to insert an already existing object into database you'll get a constrain error, all databases and most ORMs work this way. If you want it to override existing fields, you can use `InsertOrReplace` methods. If you don't want to override, you'll have to check for existence first and insert only if it doesn't already exist.